# Как сортировать массива

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка, swing, jtable

Сортирую строку. Для сортировки применяю метод: `sorted = listValue.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());`.`При сортировке почему-то берёт во внимание только первые цифры. Если входной массив`1 2 8 7 9`, то отсортирует отлично, а если` 1 8 9 81 17`, то будет так:` 1 17 8 81 9`. Почему так получается, как это исправить?

Comment: и вы не видите никакой закономерности в ряде `1 17 8 81 9` ? по какому принципу джава по вашему сравнивает два произвольных объекта, которые попадают на вход компаратора? Программа же не знает, что там у вас внутрии что именно надо сравнивать и как именно. зато знает, что у объекта есть нечто вроде `toString()` с помощью которого объект приводится к строке, а строки в свою очередь сравнивать уже можно.

Comment: потому что это лист, типизированный Object, а не Integer

Comment: @teran, закономерность я увидела. А как исправить не знаю. Нужно убрать toList? На что его заменить, toString?

Comment: @Дмитрий, так я и не указывала Integer вроде

Comment: а надо бы))) вы же хотите, чтобы джава сортировала этот в натуральном порядке (как числа), а не как строки

Comment: @Дмитрий, то есть нужно будет указать List<Integer>sorted?

Comment: вот смотрите. 1, 17, 8. отсортируем это с точки зрения чисел. тогда порядок будет такой: 1,8,17. а теперь отсортируем это с точки зрения строки. тогда получится 1, 17, 8. ведь в таблице символов нет числа 17. здесь числа от 0 до 9. тогда 1 идет перед 8. а в строке 17 первый знак один, который и сравнивается с 8. это все равно , что отсортировать строки: апрель, бард. какая разница, что вторая буква апреля п и она в алфавите находится до буквы б, с которой начинается бард. главное, что первая буква а и бард на втором месте. так и с числамаи 17 , 8, если их воспринимать как строки

Comment: в джаве строгая типизация. вы не можете просто так Object превратить Integer, прсто объявив вместо List<Object> sorted как List<Integer>sorted.

Comment: @Дмитрий автор вроде вполне ясно дала понять, что поняла, что сортируется как строки, зачем такие тирады писать тогда?

Comment: @teran виноват. дурак. исправлюсь

Comment: Ваш метод `getValueFromColumnByRow` возвращает список строк. Чтоб сортировать их как числа нужно конвертировать их в числа. Как сделать это правильно зависит от причины, по которой этот метод возвращает строки, но список объявлен как список из Object. А именно, если метод может возвращать произвольные объекты, то там могут быть не только строки с числами, но у произвольные строки и вообще не строки. Как сортировать в этом случае? Или все же гарантируется , что метод вернет числа в строковом виде?

Comment: @teran вы правы, что произвольные объекты сравнить нельзя, но неправы, что делается неявное преобразование в строку. Нет такого, метод `sorted` делает преобразование в Comparable. То что сортировка работает именно так как описано, означает, что там изначально строки в списке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если данные в списке представляют собой числа в строковом представлении, следует использовать вариант [`Stream::sorted(Comparator<? super T> comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted-java.util.Comparator-) с кастомным компаратором (в данном случае [`Comparator::comparingInt(ToIntFunction<? super T> keyExtractor)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-):

```java
List<Object> sorted = listValue.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(x -> Integer.parseInt(Objects.toString(x))))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, по идее для нахождения min и max такая же структура? Или я что-то путаю?

Comment: Да, если список отсортирован (по умолчанию в порядке возрастания), то минимальный элемент будет первый `sorted.get(0)`, а максимальный -- последний `sorted.get(sorted.size() - 1)` или при помощи `ListIterator`: `sorted.listIterator(sorted.size()).previous()`

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Скажите, как можно указать, чтобы сортировались все значения, к примеру, не только: 1 5 7 9 10, но и: 1 5,3 7,61 и т.д.?

Comment: Не совсем понял _новый_ вопрос

Comment: Как можно сделать, чтобы сортировались не только целые числа, но и дробные(7.35, 6.3)

Comment: Преобразовывать в число с плавающей точкой `Double.parseDouble` и использовать соответствующий компаратор `Comparator.comparingDouble` вместо приведения/сравнения целых чисел